# Python3: Client-Server communication

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, network-programming

Its a quite simple question, but i'm searching for hours with no result.

My use case:
one way - Client asks Server for a job
other way - Server says client to stop doing current job

So its more server-server because both are listening.
But i can't find any lib for my "wishes":
1. Win7 (bye-bye Twisted)
2. Python 3
3. simple and async(bye-bye pure sockets)

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you please explain more the type of service the client/server provides. I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: bye-bye twisted? hello [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you! but i raises other questions :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676954/non-blocking-i-o-with-asyncio